# Isomorphism of a dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

If a space $X$ is isomorphic to a dual space $Y$, then is that mean $X$ is also a dual space?

$X$ is isomorphic to $Y$ means there exist a linear map $T : X \rightarrow Y$ such that both T and $T^{-1}$ are bounded.

Comment: No, it is only *isomorphic* to. An arbitrary (normed linear) space ***is*** generally not a space of linear functionals, even if it is isomorphic to such a space. For instance, $\ell^\infty\cong(\ell^1)'.$ Would you say that $\ell^\infty$ ***is*** a dual space? It is only a space of sequences.

Comment: Or, perhaps the other way:  When we say $X$ **is** a dual space, we mean $X$ is isomorphic to a dual space.  Or maybe we mean $X$ is isometric to a dual space.

Comment: What sort of spaces are you talking about?  You say "linear" and "bounded" in there, so I guess these are normed linear spaces?

Comment: @GEdgar's comment lets me wonder: are you asking "if a (normed linear) space is "isomorphic" (in your sense) to some dual space, is it also *isometrically* isomorphic to some (other) dual space?"? If I understand correctly [OnurOktay's (now deleted) link](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-1973-0310595-8), [the answer is negative](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-037-02/S0002-9939-1973-0310595-8/S0002-9939-1973-0310595-8.pdf).

Comment: It depends what you mean by [dual space](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4124728/129912).