# Double dual and tensor product for infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, dual-spaces

It is well known that finite dimensional vector spaces (over any field $K$) canonically satisfy $V''\otimes W''\simeq (V\otimes W)''$. My question is, roughly, if this canonical map can somehow be salvaged for infinite dimensional spaces. (A more precise version is at the end).

As far as I see, there are (at least) two ways to go about constructing this isomorphism:

1. If we let $j_V:V\hookrightarrow V''$ denote the double dual
   embedding, we obtain the two natural maps $$j_{V\otimes W}:V\otimes
   W \to (V\otimes W)''$$ and $$j_V\otimes j_W:V\otimes W \to
   V''\otimes W''.$$ If $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional, both of
   these maps are isomorphisms and combine to give an isomorphism
   $V''\otimes W'' \simeq (V\otimes W)''$ that is natural in both $V$
   and $W$.
   If at least one space is infinite dimensional, however, we just conclude that both $V''\otimes W''$ and $(V\otimes W)''$ receive an embedding from $V\otimes W$.
2. The second way to go about this is to use the evaluation pairing
   $$\eta_{V,W}: V'\otimes W'\to (V\otimes W)', f\otimes g\mapsto (v\otimes w\mapsto f(v)g(w))$$
   In particular, it also follows that $V''\otimes W''\simeq (V\otimes W)''$ canonically by composing
   $$V''\otimes W'' \stackrel{\eta_{V',W'}}{\to}(V'\otimes W')' \stackrel{(\eta_{V,W}')^{-1}}{\to} (V\otimes W)''.$$
   Here, if the spaces are infinite dimensional, we can just conclude that $(V'\otimes W')$ receives a map from both $V''\otimes W''$ and $(V\otimes W)''$.

Moreover, these two constructions actually give the *same* isomorphism, as is easily verified by observing that the diagram

\begin{array}
0&&V\otimes W & \stackrel{j_V\otimes j_W}{\longrightarrow} & V''\otimes W''\newline
 (D)&&\downarrow j_{V\otimes W} & & \downarrow \eta_{V',W'}\newline
&&(V\otimes W)'' & \stackrel{\eta_{V,W}'}{\longrightarrow} & (V'\otimes W')'
\end{array}
is in fact commutative for all spaces.

In this situation, note that $\eta_{V',W'}$ is injective and $\eta_{V,W}'$ is surjective, so that there must be *some* (unnatural) embedding of $V''\otimes W'' \hookrightarrow (V\otimes W)''$ (and, likewise, quotient map going the other way). But so far I had no luck coming up with any natural (nonzero) map in any direction.

Does there exist such a canonical map? To make this precise: Are there any natural transformations between the functors $(V,W)\mapsto V''\otimes W''$ and $(V,W)\mapsto (V\otimes W)''$ that restrict to the above isomorphisms for finite dimensional spaces? If so, are there any examples that constitute a lift of the diagram $(D)$? If there are no such maps (or even consistently none, if this turns out to be sensitive to the underlying set theory), I would also be grateful for any information on that matter.

Comment: To confirm, you want to work with the algebraic dual spaces? Also would perhaps a duality (pairing) between relevant spaces work for your applications versus map restricting to iso?

Comment: Yes, this is about algebraic duals. I don't really understand your second quesion however, can you perhaps clarify? What I'm after is really *some* natural map between these spaces - if that turns out to be an embedding or a quotient map (or even iso, even though I doubt that), all the better.

Comment: If arbitrary spaces $V,V^*$ are dual in the sense of having a non-degenerate bilinear form $V\times V^*\to k$, and similarly for $W,W^*$, then the same is naturally true for $V\otimes W$ and $V^*\otimes W^*$. In the infinite-dimensional case this is sufficient for many uses of (algebraic) duality, although you won't have induced isos to the spaces of linear forms. I was just thinking that might be of use to you. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4124728/abstract-symmetric-definition-of-duality-in-linear-algebra) for more detail.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the clarification! Yes, any natural pairing in this setting would also be of interest.